# Runtime error on WGan-gp algorithm when running on GPU

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am a newbie in pytorch  and running the WGan-gp algorithm on google colab using GPU runtime. I encountered the error below. The algorithm works fine when at None runtime i.e cpu.

## Error generated during training

```
0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7e1d4849a60a> in <module>
     19             # Calculate gradient penalty on real and fake images
     20             # generated by generator
---> 21             gp = gradient_penalty(netCritic, real_image, fake, device)
     22             critic_loss = -(torch.mean(critic_real_pred)
     23                             - torch.mean(critic_fake_pred)) + LAMBDA_GP * gp

<ipython-input-15-f84354d74f37> in gradient_penalty(netCritic, real_image, fake_image, device)
      8     # image
      9     # interpolated image ← alpha *real image  + (1 − alpha) fake image
---> 10     interpolated_image = (alpha*real_image) + (1-alpha) * fake_image
     11 
     12     # calculate the critic score on the interpolated image

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

## Snippet of my WGan-gp code

```
def gradient_penalty(netCritic, real_image, fake_image, device=device):

    batch_size, channel, height, width = real_image.shape

    # alpha is selected randomly between 0 and 1
    alpha = torch.rand(batch_size, 1, 1, 1).repeat(1, channel, height, width)
    # interpolated image=randomly weighted average between a real and fake
    # image
    # interpolated image ← alpha *real image  + (1 − alpha) fake image
    interpolated_image = (alpha*real_image) + (1-alpha) * fake_image
    
    # calculate the critic score on the interpolated image
    interpolated_score = netCritic(interpolated_image)

    # take the gradient of the score wrt to the interpolated image
    gradient = torch.autograd.grad(inputs=interpolated_image,
                                   outputs=interpolated_score,
                                   retain_graph=True,
                                   create_graph=True,
                                   grad_outputs=torch.ones_like
                                   (interpolated_score)
                                   )[0]
    gradient = gradient.view(gradient.shape[0], -1)
    gradient_norm = gradient.norm(2, dim=1)
    gradient_penalty = torch.mean((gradient_norm - 1)**2)
    return gradient_penalty
```

```
n_epochs = 2000
cur_step = 0
LAMBDA_GP = 10
display_step = 50
CRITIC_ITERATIONS = 5
nz = 100

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    # Dataloader returns the batches
    for real_image, _ in tqdm(dataloader):
        cur_batch_size = real_image.shape[0]
        real_image = real_image.to(device)
        for _ in range(CRITIC_ITERATIONS):
            fake_noise = get_noise(cur_batch_size, nz, device=device)
            fake = netG(fake_noise)
            critic_fake_pred = netCritic(fake).reshape(-1)
            critic_real_pred = netCritic(real_image).reshape(-1)

            # Calculate gradient penalty on real and fake images
            # generated by generator
            gp = gradient_penalty(netCritic, real_image, fake, device)
            critic_loss = -(torch.mean(critic_real_pred)
                            - torch.mean(critic_fake_pred)) + LAMBDA_GP * gp
            netCritic.zero_grad()
            # To make a backward pass and retain the intermediary results
            critic_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
            optimizerCritic.step()

        # Train Generator: max E[critic(gen_fake)] <-> min -E[critic(gen_fake)]
        gen_fake = netCritic(fake).reshape(-1)
        gen_loss = -torch.mean(gen_fake)
        netG.zero_grad()
        gen_loss.backward()
        # Update optimizer
        optimizerG.step()

        # Visualization code ##
        if cur_step % display_step == 0 and cur_step > 0:
            print(f"Step{cur_step}: GenLoss: {gen_loss}: CLoss: {critic_loss}")
            display_images(fake)
            display_images(real_image)
            gen_loss = 0
            critic_loss = 0
        cur_step += 1
```

I tried to introduce cuda() at the lines 10 and 21 indicated in the error output.But not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach to solve this kind of error:

1. Read the error message and locate the exact line where it occured:

   ```
   ... in gradient_penalty(netCritic, real_image, fake_image, device)
         8     # image
         9     # interpolated image ← alpha *real image  + (1 − alpha) fake image
   ---> 10     interpolated_image = (alpha*real_image) + (1-alpha) * fake_image
        11 
        12     # calculate the critic score on the interpolated image

   RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, 
                 but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
   ```
2. Look for input tensors that have not been properly transferred to the correct device. Then look for intermediate tensors that have not been transferred.

   Here `alpha` is assigned to a random tensor but no transfer is done!

   ```
   >>> alpha = torch.rand(batch_size, 1, 1, 1) \
                    .repeat(1, channel, height, width)
   ```
3. Fix the issue and test:

   ```
   >>> alpha = torch.rand(batch_size, 1, 1, 1, device=fake_image.device) \
                    .repeat(1, channel, height, width)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ivan. It is running perfectly now.